# Looping thru tupule of list

Tags: list, loops, tuples, logic, combinations

I have a code like this:

```
a =(['a','b'],[1,2])
```

I need an output like this:

```
'a' 1
'b' 2
```

How to loop this through for loop.
I tried multiple ways.

Somebody help me on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

zip comes in help in these moments:

```
my_list = (['a', 'b'], [1, 2])
my_result = list(zip(*my_list))

print(my_result)
```

> Result is [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]

Then you can do whatever you want.

Hope to have been helpful